# Python nested loops with if statements unexpected result

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, nested-loops, iterable

I am trying to figure out why this code performs differently from how I would expect.
The code is:

```
for i1 in [xrange(567)]:
    W = x1[i1]
    Z = y[i1]
    ZW = np.array([z * (1/w) for z, w in zip(Z,W)])
    for j1 in [xrange(567)]:
        if j1 != i1:
            E1 = np.array([z - zw * w for z, zw, w in zip(Z,ZW,W)])
```

Where x1 is a (566,1)-array and y a (566,2)-array from a .csv file. 
Now I think that the statement `if j1 != i1:` doesn't work as it would be expected since if I try the more simple pattern:

```
for i in [range(567)]:
    for j in [range(567)]:
        if i != j:
            print i
            print j
```

It returns none

Comment: please format your code properly.

Comment: And please add *complete* code, what you expect, and what the current output is.

Comment: The statement `[xrange(567)]` created a list with a generator as it's only item. I guess you want to iterate over the numbers. Then you will have to remove the brackets.

Comment: It was a mistake I didn't mean to edit an incomplete code

Comment: Just to emphasize @KlausD., you should iterate with `for i1 in xrange(567):` (don't put it in a list).

Comment: @KlausD. I thought that I would have had without the brackets as a result only the last iteration of the loop instead of the complete W, Z and ZW arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs to be modified:

```
for i in range(567):
    for j in range(567):
        # do something here.
```

As the commenters mentioned, omit the square brackets from your `for` loop line.